# how to use Wait in Print standment in for loop python without appending into LISTs?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am wondering if its possible to execute first `print` statement and then others.
For example in below code. It can print the `prod_val` then `c`.

code:

```
l = [2,3,4]
pro_val = 1
c = 0
for i in range(len(l)):
    pro_val = pro_val * l[c]
    c = c+1
    print(pro_val)
    await  #looking something here and it print c after
    print(c)
```

expected:

```
2
6
24

1
2
3
```

Comment: What is that `await` doing there?

Comment: You want your `pro_val` to be calculated and printed in a loop. And then you want the elements of `l` or the indices _+ 1_ of `l` to be printed? Because your code currently prints the indices _+ 1_, but the output you say you want are just the elements of `l`.

Comment: sorry, i fixed it, its just counter i need to print

Answer (score 1):

You get your desired output, if you simply do two loops.

```py
l = [2, 3, 4]
pro_val = 1

for num in l:
    pro_val *= num
    print(pro_val)

for num in l:
    print(num)
```

Output:

```
2
6
24
2
3
4
```

If you want the second to print the indices shifted by one instead, you would do this instead:

```py
...
for num in l:
    pro_val *= num
    print(pro_val)

for i in range(len(l)):
    print(i + 1)
```

Output:

```
2
6
24
1
2
3
```

Not sure, why you want to throw `await`-expressions into the mix here.

---

#### PS

You seem to think that there is some magical statement, with which you can defer that second `print` in your original loop until the end of the loop, such that all those `print(c)` calls are executed after the loop. I guess just writing the algorithm accordingly is too simple...

Comment: thanks but i wanted to do it in same loop.

Comment: @guest I don't understand what your actual problem is. Who cares about the number of loops? If you have _n_ elements in your list `l`, you will need  _2n_ `print` calls to get your desired output. A loop just executes the same block of code repeatedly. It is beginning to look as though you don't understand basic control flow.